# What is the maximum capacity of paint which Mario can get?

Tags: paper-mario-color-splash

I was wondering if there was a cap to the cap of how much paint Mario can store in Huey, and if so what that cap is. That is, the number next to the MAX below the paint storage.

Comment: What do you mean, cap?

Comment: @TheGamerKing The amount of times you can upgrade your paint hammer and how much paint it could hold.

Comment: Yeah, basically that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum capacity you can get would be 600.

It is confirmed by this person who reached that amount on this [thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187636-paper-mario-color-splash/74400781/863228137) :

> I just got to 600 Max Paint, which appears to be the absolute maximum. I can still gain more EXP, but the EXP bar just rolls over back to zero when I max it out, and the Max Paint continues to remain at 600.

It also seems confirmed on this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/papermario/comments/58jmmn/tips_i_have_to_share_after_completing_color/) by someone who also reached that maximum amount :

> The absolute cap is 600

It also seemed confirmed on this [one](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii-u/187636-paper-mario-color-splash/answers/443235-whats-the-max-out-number-for-the-paint-hammer) :

> The max is 600.